# Create the SQL script for the changing the instance_type parameter in the database widgets_instances magento 2

Tags: magento2, sql, script

I have to change like this

> Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block

to

> Custom\General\Block\Widget\Block.

I am using the Replace function in the SQL , But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to change instance_type directly though database but as you asked for SQL query in your question.

So here we go

```
UPDATE widget_instance SET instance_type = "Custom\General\Block\Widget\Block" WHERE instance_type = "Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block";
```

It will update the widget_instance table and replace instance type

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I have tried this function. In my database there is lot of widgets is there . So I have crearted the custom widgets  for this. I have to change starting two word Custom\General\    for this for existed widgets which has created with different name

Comment: Update widget_instance Set instance_type = replace(instance_type, 'CMS', 'General');